# Doing math between 2 lists

Tags: c#, list, math

I get this error.

> operator * cannot be applied to operands of type double and decimal

and when I looked how to fix it there was add a suffix m or M (tried didn't work)

```
        double[] statsBase = { 708, 2.83, 288, 3.3, 63, 0.9, 10, 20, 350, 180, 900 };

        double[] statsPerLvl = { 52, 0.21, 10, 0, 2.93, 0, 1.5, 2.5, 0, 0, 0 };

        double[] statsWithLvl = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    for (int num = 0; num <= 10; num++)
{
    statsWithLvl[num] = statsBase[num] + (statsPerLvl[num] * numericUpDown_level.Value);
}
```

Comment: You need to add the definitions for your variables for us to give the right answer. Otherwise the error text should give you sufficient information to fix this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
statsWithLvl[num] = statsBase[num]
    + (statsPerLvl[num] * (double)numericUpDown_level.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `statWithLvl` and `statsBase` are doubles as there is no error for the `+` operator. The problem is that the `numericUpDown`'s Value property is a decimal. If my assumption is correct, then the simple fix is to cast the `numericUpDown`'s Value property.

Answer (score 0):

You can't multiply a decimal by a double. You can fix this by type casting.

The type decimal was designed to be useful for financial calculations since it offers high precision at the cost of reduced range for the size of the type in bytes.

You can stop using `double` and use `decimal` instead.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
If you want a numeric real literal to be treated as decimal, use the suffix m or M
```

Answer (score 0):

A suffix is only relevant on a literal.  You have no literals.  You need to convert the Value property, which is type Decimal, to a Double in order to multiply it with another Double.  Use Convert.ToDouble for the purpose.